# `import pyspark` works in Jupyter, but doesn't work with python shell/script

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to migrate `pyspark` code from `jupyter` notebook to python script. However when I tried to use

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

I have got an error `No module named 'pyspark'`

- I have tried to find all `python3` and `python2` in system, run them as a shell and have tried to import `pyspark` in each shell. However, I have got the same `No module named 'pyspark'` in each shell
- When I tried to `import findspark` with `python3`/`python2` I had got `No module named 'findspark'`
- `echo $PYTHONPATH` and `echo $SPARK_HOME`return empty string
- I have tried to find all `spark-submit` and run my script with them instead of `python3`. However, I have got an error for `argparse` use

  ```
  File "/export/home/osvechkarenko/brdmp_10947/automation_001/py_dynamic_report.py", line 206
  if args.print:
              ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ```

  When I used my script with python3 (without `pyspark`) it had worked fine.

Comment: Could you provide the output of worked `pyspark.__file__`? That helps us to identify which of your envs works.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your python interpreter is identical for jupyter and shell via:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

If that's the case, your jupyter kernel additionally adds pyspark to python path on startup. As @Sraw pointed out, you can locate pyspark via `pyspark.__file__` within your working environment.

Here is a short bash script on how pyspark can manually be added to an existing jupyter kernel under Ubuntu 16.10: [link](https://github.com/mansenfranzen/dev_envs/blob/master/ubuntu/16.04LTS/setup_sci_stack.sh#L64)